# Find operation that will produce greatest number from list

Tags: warning-messages

```
findExtremeOps[list_] :=
 (If[add[list] >= sub[list], maxNum = add[list] && maxOp = "addition",
    maxNum = sub[list] && maxOp = "subtraction"];
  If[mult[list] > max[list], 
   maxNum = mult[list] && maxOp = "multiplication", 
   If[div[list] > max[list], maxNum = div[list] && maxOp = "division",
     If[exp[list] > max[list], 
     maxNum = exp[list] && maxOp = "exponentiation", 
     checkExtremeOps[list, maxNum, maxOp]]]])

checkExtremeOps[list_, maxNum_, maxOp_] :=
 (If[maxOp == 
    "addition", (If[maxNum == sub[list], addSub = true, null]; 
    If[maxNum == mult[list], 
     If[addSub == true, addSub = false && addSubMult = true, 
      addMult = true], null]; 
    If[maxNum == div[list], 
     If[addSub == true, addSub = false && addSubDiv = true, 
      If[addSubMult == true, 
       addSubMult = false && addSubMultDiv = true, 
       If[addMult == true, addMult = false && addMultDiv = true, 
        addDiv = true]]], null];
    If[maxNum == exp[list], 
     If[addSub == true, addSub = false && addSubExp = true, 
      If[addMult == true, addMult = false && addMultExp = true, 
       If[addSubMult == true, 
        addSubMult = false && addSubMultExp = true, 
        If[addDiv == true, addDiv = false && addDivExp = true, 
         If[addSubMultDiv == true, 
          addSubMultDiv = false && addSubMultExp = true, 
          addExp = true]]]]]]), null]; 
  If[maxOp == 
    "subtraction", (If[MaxNum == mult[list], subMult = true, null]; 
    If[maxNum == div[list], 
     If[subMult == true, subMult = false && subMultDiv = true, 
      subDiv = true], null];
    If[maxNum == exp[list], 
     If[subMult == true, subMult = false && subMultExp = true, 
      If[subDiv == true, subDiv = false && subDivExp = true, 
       If[subMultDiv == true, 
        subMultDiv = false && subMultDivExp = true, 
        subExp = true]]]]), null]; 
  If[maxOp == 
    "multiplication", (If[MaxNum == div[list], multDiv = true, null];
    If[maxNum == exp[list], 
     If[multDiv == true, multDiv = false && multDivExp = true, 
      multExp = true]]), null]; 
  If[maxOp == "division", 
   If[MaxNum == exp[list], DivExp = true, null], null];
  displayExtremeOps[maxNum, maxOp, addSub, addSubMult, addSubMultDiv, 
   addSubMultDivExp, addMult, addMultDiv, addMultDivExp, addDiv, 
   addDivExp, addExp, subMult, subMultDiv, subMultDivExp, subDiv, 
   subDivExp, subExp, multDiv, multDivExp, multExp, divExp])

displayExtremeOps[maxNum_, maxOp_, addSub_, addSubMult_, 
  addSubMultDiv_, addSubMultDivExp_, addMult_, addMultDiv_, 
  addMultDivExp_, addDiv_, addDivExp_, addExp_, subMult_, subMultDiv_,
   subMultDivExp_, subDiv_, subDivExp_, subExp_, multDiv_, 
  multDivExp_, multExp_, divExp_] :=
 (StringForm[
   "The operation that produces the greatest value is `` with a value \
of ``.", maxOp, maxNum];
  (*still need to check for same numbers*))

add[list_] :=
 (For[i = 1, i <= length[list], i++, sum += list[[i]];
   Return[sum]])

sub[list_] :=
 (diff = list[[1]];
  For[i = 2, i <= length[list], i++, diff -= list[[i]];
   Return[diff]])

mult[list_] :=
 (prod = list[[1]];
  For[i = 2, i <= length[list], i++, prod *= list[[i]];
   Return[prod]])

div[list_] :=
 (quot = list[[1]];
  For[i = 2, i <= length[list], i++, quot /= list[[i]];
   Return[quot]])

exp[list_] :=
 (res = list[[1]];
  For[i = 2, i <= length[list], i++, res ^= list[[i]];
   Return[res]])
```

Things got messy when I realized I had to check for same numbers. I probably did not take the best route but this is just for a school project. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Here's what I get when I test it. Note: I still need to add the portion in the display function where I check which values are same, if at all.

Input: findExtremeOps[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

Output:

```
If[Null > max[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}], 
 maxNum = mult[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] && maxOp = "multiplication", 
 If[div[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] > max[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}], 
  maxNum = div[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] && maxOp = "division", 
  If[exp[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] > max[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}], 
   maxNum = exp[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] && maxOp = "exponentiation", 
   checkExtremeOps[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, maxNum, maxOp]]]]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve with your code. Please explain the task clearly. Also, all functions in Mathematica start with a capital letter. So `length`, `max`, `true`, `false`, ... are all not doing what you thing they are doing. Finally, check your `add`,`sub`,... functions. I think you'll find that none of them are doing what you expect. (this should also give you a hint as to why you get the result you do)

Comment: also small note, beware: `^=` is `UpSet`, and `a ^= b` is **not** equivalent to `a = a^b`. also `Return` will exit your `For` loop prematurely; check `For[i = 2, i <= 5, i++, Print[i]; Return[res]]`. Generally I think those `For` loops would be better off as [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html)'s instead, using `Plus`, `Subtract`, `Times`, and `Power`

Comment: also please check out [`Switch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html) for those nested `If` statements! :) note also that you're probably looking for `;` instead of `&&` everywhere to perform all of those `=`'s.

Comment: (here is a form for `div` to get you started: `div[list_] := Fold[Divide, list]`.) you might also benefit from more list-based, functional programming like this here. check out `Function` and `MaximalBy`.